# How to delete directories starting with "tin" in Python?

Tags: python, directory

I'd like to delete all the directories inside my *path* starting with *tin*. I am writing the codes inside ArcGIS Desktop toolbox script. every time I run my codes, a few folders associated with TIN are generated. I want to automatically delete them in the end. I tried to use the following codes but in vain.

`import shutil`

`shutil.rmtree(path + "\\tin*")`

Comment: Must you use python?  Can you use `rm -rf /my/path/tin*`?

Comment: You can do this easily in batch as well

Comment: Otherwise, you need to expand on what you want.  Is this a one time thing, or part of a program you need to write?  If it's part of a program, show us what you have so we can work within your limits.  You can update your question by pressing the edit button.

Comment: I have revised my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob.

```
import os
from glob import glob
from shutil import rmtree

path = os.getcwd()
pattern = os.path.join(path, "tin*")

for item in glob(pattern):
    if not os.path.isdir(item):
        continue
    rmtree(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the glob module and see if that helps:

```
import glob
import os

del_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'tin*'))
for del_path in del_paths:
    shutil.rmtree(del_path)
```

Comment: It gave me this error: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: @Arash You probably did `from glob import glob`.  This post assumes that you did `import glob`.  @Kurtis In the future it will help new coders if you show how you did the import as well.